Mirroring a public Google Drive to a laptop for offline use
I would like to mirror a public directory on Google Drive to a laptop. The contents of this directory are added to daily. What is the best way to do this? I have installed Google Drive for desktop and have been following instructions to go to Preferences, then Google Drive (folders from Drive) then Mirror files...how do I then specify the target public drive URL, (https//drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-JTOkg...Nj) that I want mirrored locally for offline use? Previous methods that worked involved mirroring a local shortcut to the cloud drive. This appears to no longer be an option. However, since /LZ is a shortcut this appears to be the problem. Is there a workaround for this?
Update: So the file that I am trying to mirror on the public Google Drive in the cloud is /LZ. Everyday a new directory is created in /LZ which is named YYYYMMDD_Data. In this directory are jpegs captured that day. Right clicking on /LZ/YYYYMMDD_Data produces a menu with "Offline access" offered. This is good. But what I want is this option for /LZ which will mirror the upcoming days directories as they are created.
